# How to get current location computer system in wfp

Tags: wpf

I am trying to get current location of my computer system latitude and longitude in wpf using C#.

Comment: Hi, this is most definitely not a WPF related question. WPF is mostly for displaying any information *that you already have* to the user. It is not an *information retrieval* framework. So you should look into completely different directions if you want to find out your physical location on earth. And don't let your app crash in cases where astronauts are on their way to mars while using it ;)

Comment: okay, thanks your given time.